# I want to send more than one record of sqlite to server

Tags: android, json

I want to send more than one record of `SQLite` data to server when my internet connection is come back, i have programmed a `broadcast receiver` which works when my internet is come back, but it send only one data to server, i want to send all the records of table when internet come back, suggest me that how to pass arguments to `async task` in for loop, an take each data to params.

```
public class BroadcastCreateTask extends BroadcastReceiver {
        DatabaseHandler db;
        public ProgressDialog pDialog;
        JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
        private static String url_insert_task= "";
        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

        @Override
        public  void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            db= new DatabaseHandler(context);
            boolean status = NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable(context);
            String s = String.valueOf(status);
            if(s.equals("true"))
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connected to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new createTask().execute();
            Toast.makeText(context, "data send to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(s.equals("false"))
                Toast.makeText(context, "Not Connected to internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

  class createTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String>
        {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

           List<Task> tasks = db.getAllContacts();
           for(Task t : tasks){
            String o = t.getOwner();
            String s = t.getSubject();
            String st = t.getStartDate();
            String dt = t.getDueDate();
            String c = t.getContacts();
            String sta = t.getStatus();
            String p = t.getPriority();
            String d = t.getDescription();  

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("owner",o));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject",s));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startdate",st));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("duedate",dt));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contacts",c));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status",sta));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("priority",p));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description",d));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_task, "POST", params);
            db.deleteContact(new Task(o,s));
            // check log cat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            try 
            {
             int success  = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
              if(success==1)
               {
                pDialog.dismiss();
               }
            } catch (JSONException e) 
            {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
            }
            return null;
            } // end of background method

          @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
        } // end of async task
        }`
```

Comment: You should just be able to do a query and loop over the rows in the `Cursor` returned from the query. Perhaps if you show your current implementation we could help you better.

Comment: i have written for loop in async task,but ultimately async task will be called only once, n how to take parameters to async task and set to params, i m not able to get it .

Comment: It is difficult to understand your description. Please show the code you have written to help me understand your problem.

Comment: see, in question, i have edited it, n posted code, i have to put for loop in OnReceive() method, n take all the sqlite data , n pass it to async task, but i dnt know how to make it happen,

Comment: It looks like you are making one web call for each row. Is that what you are supposed to do? Or are you supposed to make a JSONArray where each item is a database record and just make one web call for the entire data set?

Comment: for(){ 
 sqlite feilds, params = value; params= value,
asyck task (params).execute } asyc task<params>{  } i want this logic

Comment: see in async task, i have put for loop from which sqlite data comes, but i want to put for loop in Broadcast's OnReceive() method, n take sqlite data in array, and execute that async task from that OnRecieve method, u got it now .?

Comment: Please see my answer below. You have a `return null` statement that is ending your for-loop after the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the statement `return null` before the closing brace of the `for` loop. Your loop runs only once and returns, which explains why only one record is being sent.

Comment: so what should i do .?

Comment: i removed that line, but same thing happen again, it send only one data, and then force close error occurs,

Comment: haha, u knw , i got exactly what i want, i used log.d in my broadcast, but i removed log.d, bcz broadcast receiver how will do it,, :D but after removing it, i got my result,